# How to create a map-like (clouds) texture

Tags: textures

If you place a map of the world on a sphere, it will look like the image is continuous. Basically the left end of the image is sort of a continuation of the right end. You won't be able to see any cuts.

I'm trying to create a clouds texture to add to my planet such that it will seem it has clouds. I managed to create the clouds in GIMP, however, I can't figure out how to make sure the left end of my image is a smooth continuation of the right end. For example if you were to map the below image to your sphere (I removed transparency to make it clearer), there would be a very obvious transition from the right end of the image back to the left end on your sphere. How would I create a texture such that I get rid of that? [image]

Sorry for my lack of terminology.

Comment: I fail to see why this is a duplicate. I didn't ask for a code solution. I did find out though some relevant terminology from that other question: TILEABLE. I was looking for a tileable texture.

Anyway, in GIMP: Filters -> Map -> Make Seamless is a start.

Comment: If you're asking how to use GIMP to do that, this isn't the place. We're pretty big on development solutions.